# When Texture Coordinates are outside the range 0..1, they glitch, why?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, coordinates

I'm learning opengl for the android platform, everything was fine until I messed up with my texture coordinates and they end up lower than zero,
I realized that they got a little distorted and tried with higher values.

With this I found that when my textures are inside the range 0..1, my textures would look like this:

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/ngk92.jpg] (normal)

but when they are out of this range (negative or over 1) they would appear like this (in this picture ranging from 100..101):

[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/34yyc87.jpg] (broken, minecraft like even)

Is there a reason why?

Can I avoid this behaviour other than clamping my UV's?

**EDIT:**
WARP is set like this:

GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

I'm using shaders, and they are set to "mediump" precision.

**Another thing very important thing:**
I have the same program executing on windows and cannot reproduce this. Nor on emulators, this can only be reproduced in an android device

Comment: What `GL_WRAP` modes are you using?

Comment: What's the behavior you expect? The range of texture coordinates that cover the texture is 0..1. What happens if you use coordinates outside that range depends on the WRAP modes you set for your texture. So we need more details on what exactly you are trying to do, and the answer to the question @derhass was asking. Based on how the picture looks, it's most likely CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

Comment: You have tagged this as OpenGL ES... are you using shaders? Floating-point data in ES can have multiple precisions, and some precisions actually cannot represent values in that range (100-101). `lowp`, for instance, can only represent values in the range [-2.0,2.0].

Comment: @derhass: it is set as GL_REPEAT

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I was expecting the shader to repeat the pattern, the thing is I've never saw this behaviour on the computers and I got curious, and it may impact in a godray shader that uses this idea of repeating pattern for numbers that are bigger than 1. It's set as GL_REPEAT.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I set this as "mediump"